# How Can I Accept String Array through scanner class and define its size by user size

Tags: java

Is it possible for two methods to be have the same name and same parameters  and return the same type?

For example I have these two methods:

```
class Method
{

   public int mm(int a,int b)
   {
      return a+b;
   }
   public int mm(int a,int b)
   {
      return ab;
   }
   public static void main*String j[])
   {  
       Method m=new Method();
        System.out,println(m.add(12,23);
        System.out.println(m.add(12.0f,23.0f);
   }
}
```

But this code generate error it means that  return type should not same

Comment: I suggest you change the Question header for this question. This question basically clarifies concepts on method overloading and does not really talk about String array handling.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem 
was solved, especially if you solved it yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's garbage code that was clearly never compiled by the author and the subject line is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a garbage question, and should be closed. The code couldn't even compile as shown and has nothing to do with the subject line. Waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

> `Overloading` methods must differ in one of the following :

1. Number of parameters.
2. Data type of parameters.
3. Sequence of Data type of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are several syntactical errors in the code snippet you provided. Never mind, I guess the syntax got wrong while you wanted to put up the code in the question.

Coming to your query:

You see you have the exact method signatures for both your `mm` methods. Both the `mm` methods take `int a` and `int b` and `returns` an `int`.
Thus the compiler will not know what method to call because these two methods will be called in exactly the same conditions. In other words, there is no simple scenario when either of these methods will not be called.
However, if you change the arguments of either of the `mm` methods, your code will compile:

```
public int mm(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

public int mm(float a, float b) {
    return 1;
}

public static void main(String j[]) {
    Method m = new Method();
    System.out.println(m.mm(12, 23));
    System.out.println(m.mm(12.0f, 23.0f));
}
```

In the above case, the compiler will call the second `mm` method in the second call statement, `System.out.println(m.mm(12.0f, 23.0f));`

Thus here you see, you can have same `return` type.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

For such  questions, you should always consult the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html). So here we go:

**[§8.4.9. Overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9)**

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

The same holds true for interfaces:

**[§9.4.2. Overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.2)**

> If two methods of an interface (whether both declared in the same interface, or both inherited by an interface, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but different signatures that are not override-equivalent (§8.4.2), then the method name is said to be overloaded.

The term "override-equivalent" is explained here:

**[§8.4.2. Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)**

> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

The terms "signature" and "subsignature" are also explained in this paragraph, of which signature is the more important one:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

---

Summarizing this all, it means that ***the return type is not part of a method's signature***, which also means that different return types are not enough to make methods different (with respect to overloading).

Answer (score 0):

Not, Both methods have the same signature, You can cause the program to become aware of itself and destroy the world. Try something like this:

```
public int mm(int a ,int b, int op)
{
    int result = 0;
    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        result =  a + b;
        break;
    case 2:
         result = a * b;

    case 3: 
          result = a - b;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return result;
}

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {  
       Method m = new Method();
      System.out.println(  m.mm(5,5,1));
   }
```